# How to create a random computer choice, except the choice you already choose?

Tags: javascript, html, random

I'am making a boxing game. The user can choose between three boxers. The computer can choose between the remainder two(that you don't have choosen).
https://jsfiddle.net/1ehpxto6/
 My HTML is

```
<p id="printNames0"></p>

<div id="jouwbokser">
<h1>Kies Jouw Bokser!</h1>
<img id="bokser1" onClick="gevecht1()"  src="img/bokser1.png"     alt="bokserlinks" />
<img id="bokser2" onClick="gevecht2()"  src="img/bokser2.png" alt="boksermidden" />
<img id="bokser3" onClick="gevecht3()"  src="img/bokser3.png" alt="bokserrechts" />

</div>
```

My javascript is:

```
var bokser = ['bokser1', 'bokser2', 'boker3' ];
var userChoice;
var comChoice;



//functie die laat zien welke bokser je hebt gekozen.
function greet(){
return ("Je hebt" + userChoice.toLowerCase() + "gekozen");
}

//functie die tekst showt in html
function printToPage(test){
var content = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
content.innerHTML = ("<p>" + test + "</p>" + content.innerHTML);

}


//bokser object
var bokser1 = {
hitpoints: 100,
attack1: 2,
attack2:5,
attack3:8,
attack4:12
};

var bokser2 = {
hitpoints:100,
attack1:2,
attack2:5,
attack3:8,
attack4:12
};

var bokser3 = {
hitpoints:100,
attack1:2,
attack2:5,
attack3:8,
attack4:12
    };



//kies bokser
//andere boksers worden display none als bokser gekozen is
//kies bokser1
function gevecht1(){
document.getElementById("bokser2").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("bokser3").style.display = "none";
userChoice = bokser[0];
printToPage(greet());
}

//kies bokser2
function gevecht2(){
document.getElementById("bokser1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("bokser3").style.display = "none";
userChoice = bokser[1];
printToPage(greet());
}

//kies bokser3
function gevecht3(){
document.getElementById("bokser1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("bokser2").style.display = "none";
userChoice = bokser[2];
printToPage(greet());
}
```

Has anyone an idea how to create the computer choice random, except the one you choose before.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could do what you wanted just by doing this:

```
user_choice = getUserChoice();

choices.splice(choices.indexOf(user_choice),1);

computer_choice = choices[ Math.round(Math.random()*(choices.length-1)) ];
```

*EDIT*: It seems this could be simpler. See above.

What you are looking for is to permute the boxes, except for the ones that have been chosen already. Here is a function (which uses the function `permute`) below:

```
function permute_except(user_choice, remaining_choices) {
  // find the choice
  var index = remaining_choices.indexOf(user_choice);
  // remove the choice 
  remaining_choices.splice(index,1);
  // return the remaining ones, permuted
  return permute(remaining_choices);
}
```

Use it like

```
user_choice = getUserChoice(); // somehow

possible_choices = permute(user_choice, possible_choices);
var computer_choice_i_1 = possible_choices.pop();

user_choice = getUserChoice(); // somehow

possible_choices = permute_except(user_choice, possible_choices);
var computer_choice_i_2 = possible_choices.pop(); 

// ... etc
```

*EDIT:*

I thought the thing you are looking for is called a permutation. So what follows describes that, actually what you are looking for is different, so see above.

A permutation is just a way of arranging a set of things in some order (maybe different to how you found it). You would like a random permutation of your boxes. 
`permute` (hopefully clear enough) returns a permutation of the array, `choices` (or of the array [0,1,2] if you don't pass an argument to the `permute`):

```
function permute(choices) { 
   choices = choices || [0,1,2];
    var random_choices = [];
    while(choices.length > 0) {
      var choice_index = Math.round(Math.random()*(choices.length-1));
      random_choices.push(choices[choice_index]); 
      choices.splice(choice_index,1);
    }
    return random_choices;
}
```

Alternately you can implement a different type of permutation function, like the algorithm in [`RC4`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Key-scheduling_algorithm_.28KSA.29), that simply swaps values at randomly chosen pairs of indexes in the array.

If you want to get a little more functionality, you could implement a permutation that is `non-fixed`, i.e., that has no fixed point. This is also called a [`derangement`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

The rest, is up to you, good luck!

Comment: it is like a rock paper, scissor. So is it possible to do it with an if/else statement? The only different with rock, paper, scissor it that the comChoice can choose between the remainder two.

Comment: You can try it and find out!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is basically like choosing lottery balls without returning ball back to the box. It is known as Fisher–Yates shuffle (F-Y-Knuth shuffle), and it is O(n) algorithm described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle